# Is there a way to represent a binary/non-binary tree/graph/trie like structure in a Github README.md?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

In my Githubs repos documentation I want to represent a binary tree structure like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do that with Github flavored markdown, besides just creating it with art/uml diagramming (using plain image file)?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not supported by [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/) alone.

You would need to call a third-party online service, like [**g.gravizo.com**](http://g.gravizo.com/) in order to include any graph from a text description.

See for instance [`TLmaK0/gravizo`](https://github.com/TLmaK0/gravizo)

```
![Alt text](https://g.gravizo.com/source/custom_mark10?https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FTLmaK0%2Fgravizo%2Fmaster%2FREADME.md)
<details> 
<summary></summary>
custom_mark10
  digraph G {
    size ="4,4";
    main [shape=box];
    main -> parse [weight=8];
    parse -> execute;
    main -> init [style=dotted];
    main -> cleanup;
    execute -> { make_string; printf};
    init -> make_string;
    edge [color=red];
    main -> printf [style=bold,label="100 times"];
    make_string [label="make a string"];
    node [shape=box,style=filled,color=".7 .3 1.0"];
    execute -> compare;
  }
custom_mark10
</details>
```

That would be generated/displayed as:

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/1243ee2a3700c5eb0e9b326a8ad1f49d26ac9956/68747470733a2f2f672e67726176697a6f2e636f6d2f736f757263652f637573746f6d5f6d61726b31303f68747470732533412532462532467261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d253246544c6d614b3025324667726176697a6f2532466d6173746572253246524541444d452e6d64]